# how to get the .class files before using hadoop command to run it?

Tags: hadoop, javac

I am new to Hadoop and I am reading the 'Definitive Guide' book.

In ch02 there is a simple hadoop example which has a mapper, a reducer and a class with main function.

As the book says, I have to use

```
% export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=hadoop-examples.jar
% hadoop MaxTemperature input/ncdc/sample.txt output
```

to run the code. The MaxTemperature is the class with the main method, followed by the input and the output path.

When I ran the command above I got exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MaxTemperature
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MaxTemperature
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: MaxTemperature. Program will exit.
```

I found out that I did not have the .class files so I tried to used javac to compile the java files. Then it gave me errors saying that all classes from Hadoop cannot be found.

I turned to eclipse, created a project with hadoop build path. It worked fine obviously, and I found the .class files in the bin folder from the eclipse project. By this time, since I got those .class files, I can use :

```
% hadoop MaxTemperature input/ncdc/sample.txt output
```

My question is:

How can I use configure the hadoop classpath properly to use javac to compile the java files and get the .class files?

(I used `hadoop classpath` and found out the hadoop_classpath is sooo long. Do I have to set up the classpath as that long?)

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

javac -classpath  solve all the problems!!!